# Is $\mathbb Z[1/2]$ a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Consider the subring 
$$
 \mathbb Z\left[\frac{1}{2}\right] = \left\{ \frac{k}{2^n} : n \ge 0 \right\}.
$$
As $1/2$ is the root of $2X - 1$, this is an intergral extension. Now according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element#Equivalent_definitions) we have the equivalence 
that if $A \subseteq B$ are rings with $b \in B$
$$
 \mbox{$b$ is integral over $A$} \Leftrightarrow
 \mbox{the subring $A[b]$ is a finitely generated $A$-module}.
$$
But why is $\mathbb Z[1/2]$ a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-module, as I see it the elements $1, 1/2, 1/4, \ldots$ are infinitely many generators?

Comment: $2X -1 $ is not monic and thus the corresponding extension is not integral. Or rather from this polynomial you cannot conclude that it is integral (which it is indeed not).

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck Oh, thats exactly the crucial thing which I missed from the definition! Thank you. Maybe you like to put this as an answer so I can accept it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically just my above comment posted as an answer as to conclude this question:

The polynomial $2X-1$ is not monic, which is a crucial part in the definition of an integral extension. While this does not necessarily mean that the extension is not integral (there could be another polynomial that does the trick) it at least does not allow us to make the conclusion.

Indeed the extension is not integral as you have correctly identified an infinite generating set, no finite subset of which remains a generating set.